# Moq setup doesn't work for interface method and enters the moqed method with IQueryable result

Tags: linq, mocking, installation, moq, iqueryable

I have problems with mocking a method named Query that returns an interface IQueryable, and I don't know why.

The method I try to mock with Moq framework:

```
public class ObjectContextRepository : IObjectContextRepository
    {
        .....
        private ObjectContext _objectContext = null;      
        public IQueryable<TEntity> Query<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
        {
// Moq Setup doesn't work and debugger enters this code:
            return ObjectContext.CreateObjectSet<TEntity>();
        }
...
}
```

the test example:

```
ObjectContextRepositoryFactory = new Mock<IObjectContextRepositoryFactory>();
ObjectContextRepositoryFactory.Setup(x => x.NewInstance(false))
                                          .Returns(new ObjectContextRepository(It.IsAny<string>()));

CurrencyRateManager = new CurrencyRateManager(new ObjectContextRepositoryFactory("connection"));

ObjectContextRepository = new Mock<IObjectContextRepository>();
CurrencyExchangeRate rate1 = new CurrencyExchangeRate {EXCHANGE_DATE = new DateTime(2012, 09, 07)};
CurrencyExchangeRate rate2 = new CurrencyExchangeRate {EXCHANGE_DATE = new DateTime(2012, 09, 06)};

IList<CurrencyExchangeRate> list = new List<CurrencyExchangeRate> { rate1, rate2 };

// I wait that Query() method will return me  a list with rates. 
ObjectContextRepository.Setup(x => x.Query<CurrencyExchangeRate>()).Returns(list.AsQueryable());

using (IObjectContextRepository context = ObjectContextRepositoryFactory.Object.NewInstance())
            {
// Mock doesn't work and debugger enters custom method context.Query<>() and throws an exception
var maxDateQuery = context.Query<CurrencyExchangeRate>()
                    .Where(c => c.EXCHANGE_DATE < new DateTime(2012, 09, 07));
            }
```

PS. Yes, I know, that I have to use the integration tests, but it's my task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your factory returns `new ObjectContextRepository(It.IsAny<string>())` instead of your mock (which is even defined later that your factory). So your test executes against real implementation, not mock.

BTW, there's no sense in using `It.IsAny<string>()` inside `Returns`, it does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Sometime it's very effective to stop exploring problem and post a question. The answer comes quickly....

the reason was in Object property of Mocked objects.
I changed

```
ObjectContextRepositoryFactory = new Mock<IObjectContextRepositoryFactory>();
ObjectContextRepositoryFactory.Setup(x => x.NewInstance(false))
                                          .Returns(new ObjectContextRepository(It.IsAny<string>()));

CurrencyRateManager = new CurrencyRateManager(new ObjectContextRepositoryFactory("connection"));
```

to

```
        ObjectContextRepository = new Mock<IObjectContextRepository>();

        ObjectContextRepositoryFactory = new Mock<IObjectContextRepositoryFactory>();
        ObjectContextRepositoryFactory.Setup(x => x.NewInstance(false))
                                      .Returns(**ObjectContextRepository.Object**);

        CurrencyRateManager = new CurrencyRateManager(**ObjectContextRepositoryFactory.Object**);
```

and it works.